# How to make an auto scroller game using sprite Kit?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I am trying to make an auto scroller game. I have my Character and my ground as two separate nodes. My problem is that I don't if I should make the character or my ground move indefinitely, and how.

I did try moving my player indefinitely but I don't think I am doing it right.

```
let move = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.moveTo(x: player.position.x + 10, duration: 1))
        player.run(move)
```

For the moment the player kinda trips on the ground. I am completely lost, I hope someone has done this before and can give me the answer. Thank You Very Much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok found the answer myself
I should have tried this before 
anyway what I did Is make my ground run the move action

```
let move = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.moveBy(x: -200, y: 0, duration: 1))
        GroundNode.run(move)
```